# MySQL (8.0.24 Community Server - GPL) does not rollback transaction inside a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL (8.0.24 Community Server - GPL). When there is an exception in my stored procedure, MySQL does not rollback. Here is a script to demo:

First run this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE already_exists (
             ROW_ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
             PRIMARY KEY  (row_id))
             ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now create this stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure test_proc()
begin
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        resignal;
    END;

  start transaction;

    set @sql = concat('create table tbl1 (
        ROW_ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY  (row_id))
        ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;'
    );
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;

    set @sql = concat('CREATE TABLE already_exists (
        ROW_ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY  (row_id))
        ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
    ');
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;

  commit;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Now call the stored procedure:

```
call test_proc();
```

**Expected:**

The table `tbl1` should not be created since table `already_exists` already exists.

**Observed:**

I get this error:

```
mysql> call test_proc();
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'already_exists' already exists
```

but MySQL also creates `tbl1` in the system. Is this a bug or does anyone how what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html ? The transaction is implicitly committed by executing a DDL statement.

Comment: thanks. I see this now: The CREATE TABLE statement in InnoDB is processed as a single transaction. This means that a ROLLBACK from the user does not undo CREATE TABLE statements the user made during that transaction. Maybe you want to put it as an answer and I will accept it. Also mention in the answer what should I do to get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL statements cause an [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html). The first CREATE TABLE statement in your procedure commits the transaction. You can't roll back a DDL statement in MySQL.

You could use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS syntax, so that if one of the tables already exists, it will not cause an error.

Or if you want to skip creating both tables if either one already exists, then you should check first if they exist:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('tbl1', 'already_exists');
```

I would write it something like the following:

```
DELIMITER !!
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE tbl1 VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE already_exists VARCHAR(64);

  SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO tbl1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='tbl1';

  IF tbl1 IS NULL THEN
    CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
      ROW_ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY  (row_id)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
  END IF;

  SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO already_exists FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME='already_exists';

  IF already_exists IS NULL THEN
    CREATE TABLE already_exists (
      ROW_ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
      PRIMARY KEY  (row_id)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
  END IF;

END !!
DELIMITER ;
```

You don't need to use `PREPARE`/`EXECUTE` to run a create table, unless you need to make some of the columns or other syntax dynamic. But for your example, it can be done directly as shown above.

Comment: can you extend you answer and include what code needs to be written to abort if any table already exists?

Comment: I've written an example procedure. If you want different logic, I'll leave that to you to implement.

Comment: Thanks. I have copy of your book btw!

Comment: Btw, can't we just do create table if not exists instead of doing all the checks in the answer?

Comment: That was my first suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the version 8.0.15 on your Windows10 LocalComputer because is the lasted stabled version that Microsoft uses on Azure Services for seriously companies that offers the MySQL Database Service, in my personal case in this 2021 year I been affected with this bug and has spend 3 days....3 days!!!! to solve this.
Good Luck.
**[See the actual MySQL Bug][1]**
[1]: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99940